# VBA - Table order by ascending date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a the following code were I want to order a table by ascending date:

```
Set TableCreated = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$8:$F$22"), , xlNo)
TableCreated.Name = matchCheck
With TableCreated.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:= _
            Range("[[#All],[Column1]]"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

But the code is failing. 
I tried to find the solution by recording a macro and check the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("T1_Migration_C5_BKO").ListObjects( _
    "T1_Migration_C5_BKO").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("T1_Migration_C5_BKO").ListObjects( _
    "T1_Migration_C5_BKO").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "T1_Migration_C5_BKO[[#All],[Column1]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("T1_Migration_C5_BKO").ListObjects( _
    "T1_Migration_C5_BKO").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
```

The problem here is that the table is called by is name and not the parameter TableCreated.

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're naming the table, use that name in the range argument:

```
Set TableCreated = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$8:$F$22"), , xlNo)

matchCheck = "MyTable"
TableCreated.name = matchCheck

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(matchCheck).Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range(matchCheck & "[Column1]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Apply
End With
```

Also, don't forget the .Apply!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do it like this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("T1_Migration_C5_BKO").ListObjects(TableCreated.Name).Sort
```

Thus, the table would be called by its name, e.g. `TableCreated.Name`. It should work.